# Slow Wired Connection on 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet

I have very slow wired connection (less than 10Mbps), yet WiFi is fine at over 300 Mbps. I'd much prefer to use ethernet, but am currently on WiFi until I can find a solution. Most issues I've found on here relate to slow wifi, which isn't the case here.

Relatively new to Ubuntu, but willing to try anything and will provide any outputs needed.

E: output of lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3:

```
2a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 done and ty

Comment: There may be many reasons. It could be a bad cable, bad connection, etc, or some bug. Check the connections and try to boot with Ubuntu 18.04 liveusb to see if it is a kernel issue. Or install some other mainline kernel. I am not familiar with this specific adapter.

Comment: Not sure if you have found a solution to your problem, but it seems as though we have very similar hardware and software configurations (both ASRock MBs with the I211 chip and the same exact software version and revision) and we are both having the same exact problem. I have tried pretty much everything I've seen online on this issue and can not find any solution. I am running ParrotOS (based on Debian). On the same machine on a Windows boot I get 700Mbps Up/Down and then I boot into Linux to get 7 down and 70 up. If you solved your problem I'd be happy to know how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Right after posting the comment on your OP I solved the issue for me:

`$ sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off`

After executing that, I ran a speed test and got the same exact speeds I expect on Windows (slightly lower, but that could just be the time of day, it is a negligible difference).

The one downside is that now the driver is entirely confused:

```
$ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off (auto)
```

I'm not too worried about that right now, I have a big project I need to finish. If I figure out the exact process of resolving the driver having no idea what I am asking of it, I will update this post. Hope this helps!

EDIT: Briefly wanted to note that if you try to use the ethtool command as I did, it appears it will not remain as you want it the next time you boot up and you will need to execute the command once again. I believe with `autoneg off`, the settings should have remained even after reboot but its likely that it is resetting itself due to the `speed` and `duplex` args being out of bounds. Like I said, I'll update with a fix for that once I figure it out.

Comment: im getting `netlink error: link settings update failed` and `netlink error: Invalid argument`